# Mac running c program using gcc

Tags: c, macos, gcc

Whenever I try to compile my c program on mac it gives the following error. I am completely clueless about it.

> 'sys/cdefs.h' file not found

Comment: Are you in the terminal?  Try `ls sys/cdefs.h`.  Is it there?

Comment: No its not there. It says not found. What should I do ?

Comment: How about if you type in "`ls -l /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h`", do you see it now?

Comment: No its not there too.

Comment: Maybe you need to update `gcc` or better yet, use `clang`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you installed "Xcode Command Line Tools" ? just install it in your terminal.

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Xcode, if you haven't already.

Then, from Terminal do the following to avoid future *similar* (not necessary just for this, I don't think) issues in future:

```
xcode-select --install
```

This will automatically download and install the latest XCode Command Line Tools.

Answer (score 0):

From [Xcode 4.3](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html), the Xcode is installed from Mac App Store. By default, there is no command line tools. Probably you have missed it. They can be installed using the Components tab of the Downloads preferences panel.

Comment: That is true on OS X 10.7 (Lion) and 10.8 (Mountain Lion).  As of OS X 10.9 (Mavericks), you need to use `sudo xcode-select --install` as others have noted.